# What's the use cases of rule engines in Protege?

Tags: drools, protege, jess, pellet, swrl

When writing new rules in Protege with SWRLTab and SQWRLTab, we define constrained rules in SWRL and query with SQWRL by using semantic reasoners such as FaCT++, Pellet, ..., or rule engines such as Drools or Jess. But because Protege limits its functionality, we cannot use Drools/Jess to define complex ontology rules or write rules in their own programming languages.

My question is: What's the purpose of Drools and Jess in Protege when we cannot use their complete features?

Comment: Surely one needs a rule engine to evaluate rules, so why are you wondering about some rule engine being used?

Answer (score 0):

Drools and Jess have a higher power than SWRL, but Protégé supports SWRL (in that it supports OWL), so the use case is to support multiple SWRL implementations.

Not all implementations are equal, but I don't think it's a requirement that all power be used, since it does not fit in the host language.